# Collapse and expand div without scrollbars appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using Jquery to try to collapse a div.  The  element to be collapsed sits above a footer on the page, as illustrated below:

[image: Initial state]

I have a button on the page that when clicked on, calls .animate() to move the div above the footer down so it appears to slide behind the footer and out of view - basically, to collapse down.

However, when the div moves beyond the bottom of the window, the browsers vertical scrollbar becomes active until I hide the div being collapsed, ie:

[image: div collapses down behind footer]

I would like to see the div collapse down to nothing WITHOUT the vertical scrollbar effect.

I also tried to animate on the height, but that causes the div to shrink starting at the bottom moving UP until the height is zero.

What is the trick to having a div collapse DOWN to nothing without having the vertical scroll bar becoming active?  Do I have to adjust both top and height?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should know by now that questions like these need a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry - took less time to illustrate via graphic than trying to strip out all the code and create a working example that illustrated the problem -- will try to do better next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the following worked using the JQuery .animate() method.

```
var elm = $('#my_div');    /* The element to expand or collapse */
var t = 589;               /* Top position of element */
var h = 200;               /* Height of element */

// Set initial position and height ...

elm.css({ 'top': t + 'px' });
elm.css({ 'height': h + 'px' });
```

**To collapse the element:**

```
/*
Set the "new" top position which we will animate to; this causes the
element to slide down while simultaneously adjusting the height
to zero, giving a collapse effect.  Note that if we did NOT adjust the
height down to zero and the element moves outside of the browsers
window, the browsers scrollbars would become active, which is NOT what
we want ...
*/

t = t + h;

elm.animate({ top: t, height: 0 }, 400, function () { /* Done */ });
```

**To expand the element:**

```
t = t - h;

elm.animate({ top: t, height: h }, 400, function () { /* Done */ });
```

The above works without activating the browsers vertical scrollbars as long as the div being animated does not move outside of the browsers window bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `overflow: hidden;` with CSS to your dynamic element. Something like this:

```
#yourDivElement{
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

That should get rid of any scrollbars appearing on your div. See:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssreF/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: No effect - as the div moves down in the window, the BROWSERS vertical scroll bar becomes visible -- most likely because the div is moving below the window bottom.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

use `slideToggle()` method of jquery. here is code.

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">

        <div id="target-div">
            Collapse div down <br/>behind footer without vertical <br/>scrollbar being actived
        </div>
        <div>
            footer
        </div>
        <button id="clickable-button">Click here</button>
    </div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#clickable-button').on('click', function(e){
        $('#target-div').slideToggle();
    });

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: SlideToggle does prevent the browsers scroll bars from appearing -- HOWEVER-- the div I want to collapse should collapse down (move top of div down until it reaches the bottom and height becomes zero); instead, SlideToggle collapses the div from the bottom to the top  (bottom of div moves up to top until height is zero) --  I need to collapse from top to bottom.  Will check if there is a way to reverse direction using slideToggle().   Thanks for the suggestion.